# Complexity of multiple-layer DES

Tags: encryption, cryptography, des

How does the complexity of brute force attacks on des scale as you add multiple layers of it? I'm trying to understand how it scales from des, 2des, 3des, and 4des but I haven't been able to find anywhere that explains it very well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked on crypto.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: requested migration instead due to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Security of DES algorithm with additional layers is determined by the Meet in the Middle attack, so it scales as this:

DES -> 56 bit

2DES-> 57 bit(Meet in the Middle attack)

3DES-> 112 bit( Actually the security is 2^112 + 2^56 which is dominated by 2^112)

4DES-> 113 bit(Meet in the Middle Attack)

5DES-> 224 bit(Same case in 3DES, 2^224 + 2^112 security which is dominated by 2^224)

So you get the idea. If you want a more detailed answer on the meet in the middle attack, how much storage it requires etc. You can read the top answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25623/meet-in-the-middle-attack-on-3des).

Comment: This question isn't complete: 3DES only has a security of ~112 bits if three different keys are used. For two key 3DES the security is around 63 to 80 bits, depending on which attacks are feasible: i.e. it has insufficient security, while 3 key triple DES still has acceptable security. Use AES or it is more secure *and* much faster. GCM is a nice mode to use.

Comment: True, I made an assumption in my answer. Additionally, there is chance of choosing weak keys where encrypting the plaintext twice will result in unencrypted plaintext or choosing semi weak keys which will result in key pairs that encrypting the ciphertext which is the result of the encryption with the other key in the pair, will result in the plaintext message.

Comment: And the block size is too small for some modes of operation, and it doesn't get accelerated on modern CPU's, it doesn't support authenticated encryption well, it uses cumbersome parity bits in the keys etc. etc. DES was the *reason* for AES. But that wasn't the question, voted up, but beware of 2 key 3DES.

Comment: I am not really an expert on DES, especially the engineering parts, thanks for sharing such information.